# How to rotate forcefully in my SDK VideoViewController to landscape orientation when app supports only portrait orientation in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, orientation, screen-orientation

am developing SDK for video player. But the problem is video auto rotation. When the app supports for both portrait and land scape it works fine. When app supports only portrait app then the auto rotation fails. How do i do the forceful **.all** orientation from SDK side.

One solution is by implementing func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask in AppDelegate it will work.

One more solution is overriding shouldAutorotate(), supportedInterfaceOrientations() in my VideoViewController this works only when app too supports both(PORTRAIT and LANDSCAPE) orientation.

But in my case SDK needs to be handle the orientation, because am presenting the VideoViewController above any visible controller. and am not exposing my VideoViewController to app.

How can i achieve it.. Any solution.

Comment: This is not duplication of that question. App supports only portrait orientation. SDK wants to rotate the UIViewController to Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is already in portrait you won’t need to change anything. If not, make sure that only portrait is selected.
[image]

In Your AppDelegate add this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
        if let vcp = rootViewController as? ViewControllerRotateProtocol, vcp.canRotate() {
            // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller

            return [.landscapeLeft , .landscapeRight]
        }
    }
    return application.supportedInterfaceOrientations(for: window)
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
    if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

Create one protocol: and you can expose this protocol to the app.

```
protocol ViewControllerRotateProtocol {
    func canRotate() -> Bool
}
```

In Your View Controller, add this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerRotateProtocol {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [.landscapeLeft , .landscapeRight]
}

func canRotate() -> Bool {
    return true
} }
```

Comment: That works when AppDelegate knows the controller class. But here AppDelegate don't know the ViewController class name. SDK presents the VideoViewController on top of any presented controller.